# MySQL connection throws an error after a long wait

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, docker

I am gonna crash my laptop. I reistalled mysql and docker bunch of times, cause every time i create docker container and connect to it through mysql i have an error. Every time error is unique. NOW, when i connect with the bash command `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P80 -u root -p`
i wait about 4 minutes and then get an error:

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

BUT, 1 hour before i created docker container and connected to it through mysql and all succseded. I've run out of energy and ideas

If somebody wants to recommend to enter `mysqld: ALL` to hosts.deny/allow - NO. I already did that

MySQL service status:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-05-08 22:15:54 MSK; 10min ago
    Process: 27811 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 27819 (mysqld)
     Status: "Server is operational"
      Tasks: 37 (limit: 9348)
     Memory: 399.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
             └─27819 /usr/sbin/mysqld

мая 08 22:15:35 rolf-pc systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
мая 08 22:15:54 rolf-pc systemd[1]: Started MySQL Community Server.
```

Docker status:

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-05-08 20:02:04 MSK; 2h 26min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 24218 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 28
     Memory: 104.4M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             ├─24218 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
             ├─27632 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8080 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 80
             └─27639 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 8080 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 80

мая 08 20:02:02 rolf-pc dockerd[24218]: time="2022-05-08T20:02:02.321079125+03:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight_device"
мая 08 20:02:02 rolf-pc dockerd[24218]: time="2022-05-08T20:02:02.321316259+03:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
мая 08 20:02:02 rolf-pc dockerd[24218]: time="2022-05-08T20:02:02.960223030+03:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. >
мая 08 20:02:03 rolf-pc dockerd[24218]: time="2022-05-08T20:02:03.218556775+03:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
мая 08 20:02:04 rolf-pc dockerd[24218]: time="2022-05-08T20:02:04.218846606+03:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=4433bf6 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.15
мая 08 20:02:04 rolf-pc dockerd[24218]: time="2022-05-08T20:02:04.219129724+03:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
мая 08 20:02:04 rolf-pc systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
мая 08 20:02:04 rolf-pc dockerd[24218]: time="2022-05-08T20:02:04.571320378+03:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
мая 08 22:12:17 rolf-pc dockerd[24218]: time="2022-05-08T22:12:17.188503840+03:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=7456bdd6179cde164b5a5ca92970f35a8d696de3b37c3>
мая 08 22:14:19 rolf-pc dockerd[24218]: time="2022-05-08T22:14:19.206500663+03:00" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=7456bdd6179cde164b5a5ca92970f35a8d696de3b37c3>
```

Container:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                        NAMES

1b0a8e0cab96   mysql:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   15 minutes ago   Up 14 minutes   3306/tcp, 33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp   TEST_SQL
```

Comment: How are you running your Docker container? (Command / docker file / docker compose etc)

Comment: $ sudo docker run --name TEST_SQL -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=0000 -p 8080:80 -d mysql:latest

Comment: Are you running two instances of mysql, one in docker and one as a regular system service? Which are you connecting to?

Comment: You haven't posted any of your actual config, so I'll base my question on the usual defaults:  Why are you trying to talk to mysql on port 80? It runs on 3306.

Comment: 3306 is busy with mysqld. Even after i deleted container and volume

Comment: So ... if you're not trying to talk to mysqld (which, to me, seems to be the logical choice - having the mysql client talk to the mysql server), what are you hoping to achieve with `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P80 -u root -p`?

Comment: i cant create container on 3306 cause its busy so i created container on 80 port..

Comment: And which port inside the container is mysqld running on?

Comment: 3306 and 80 ports

Comment: How did you trick mysqld to listen on more than one port?

Comment: i dunno, but thats true. I ran netstat. Also i broke docker and mysql after 5 or 6 reinstallations....

Answer (score 0):

I just reinstalled docker and mysql